# which table is faster in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `htmlcode_1` (
  `global_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`global_id`),
  KEY `k_site` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `htmlcode_2` (
  `global_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_id`,`global_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

which one should be faster for selects and why?

```
'select * from table where site_id=%s'
```

Comment: Your two tables describe different entities. If `global_id` is your actual primary key (it is probably unique), don't choose a different pk - as it does not enforce this uniqueness anymore. You should not select your primary key that way. An additional index will have the same effect (on speed for that query) in this situation. Regarding only the speed, Bill gave you the answer.

Comment: @Solarflare - In MySQL, a `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition, `UNIQUE`; there is no "probably unique" about it.

Comment: @RickJames I meant: `global_id` is probably the value that inherently should be unique by what it describes (otherwise the first table would not be possible). It will lose this attribute if evg uses `(site_id, global_id)` as the pk just to try to make that query faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter table is probably slightly faster for that SELECT query, assuming the table has a nontrivial number of rows.

When querying InnoDB by primary key, the lookup is against the clustered index for the table.

Secondary key lookups require a lookup in the index, then that reveals the primary key value, which is then used to do a lookup by primary key. So this uses two lookups.

Comment: Two lookups only if there are any other columns.  Otherwise, the two tables are comparably fast.  @Evg - If there are other columns, you _must_ say so, else we could give you the wrong answer.

Comment: @RickJames, fair enough. In this case, the example shows no other columns, so we get covering indexes anyway. But I assume it's not likely to be this simple of a table in reality.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to use a PRIMARY KEY is to allow for either quick access *OR* REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY (`CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY ...`)

In your second example, you do not have the proper key for referential integrity if any other table refers to your table. In that case, other operations will be very very slow.

The differences in speed in either case for your particular case should be too small and trivial, but the proper design will dictate the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

The first table represents many "globals" in each "site".  That is, a "many-to-one" relationship.  But it is the "wrong" way to do it.  Instead the `Globals` table should have a column `site_id` to represent such a relationship to the `Sites` table.  Meanwhile, the existence of `htmlcode_1` is an inefficient waste.

The second table may be representing a "many-to-many" relationship between "sites" and "globals".  If this is what you really want, then see [*my tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .  Since you are likely to map from globals to sites, another index is needed.